# Sequence generator with MySQL & JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

In a spring boot application for generating id for my entity class TableTypeEntity, I want to use sequence generator.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TABLE_TYPE_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "t_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "t_generator", sequenceName = "TABLE_SEQUENCE", initialValue=1)
private Long tableTypeId;
```

In mysql database I created a table TABLE_SEQUENCE.

```
 CREATE TABLE `TABLE_SEQUENCE` (
  `next_val` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into TABLE_SEQUENCE VALUES(0);
```

But the first entity it created has an id of -49. I was not happy with it. So I dropped the table, recreated it with next_val 1. Now the entity it created has an id of -48. I do not want id to be a  negative value. Why it is behaving in a weird manner?

Comment: What is your JPA provider, hibernate? Some have different mechanisms to determine what values can be used (given say a value of 100, some think it can use values 51-100, while others may try to use 100-149).

Answer (score 0):

JPA defaults the [allocationSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#allocationSize()) to 50, so when it gets an initial value of (0) from the sequence, it thinks it has been given values in the (-49,0) range to use. A higher allocation size is generally more efficient as the JPA provider can store them instead of hitting the sequence in the database for each and every insert. You must have the allocationSize match your sequence definition.

Comment: So should I make initial value 50? or initial value remains 0 as it is but allocation size 1?